# Load safari from ipad application

Tags: ipad, web, safari

Heey,

Does anybody know how to start safari from a ipad application?

I wan't an info view in my application with a button to my website. The 'things' application does it, so i know it is possible.
Just don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See UIApplication's [-openURL:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW14). This "does the right thing" for the http:, https:, tel:, and mailto: schemes.

Answer (score 1):

On your button action place this code:

```
[
    [UIApplication sharedApplication] 
       openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourwebsite.com"]
];
```